# Singly linked list, how to return a pointer to a new node

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct nodeStruct {
    int value;
    struct nodeStruct *next;
}

struct nodeStruct* List_createNode(int item) {
    nodeStruct* tempNode;
    tempNode->value = item;
    nodeStruct* node = malloc ( sizeof(tempNode) );
    return nodeStruct;
}
```

This is what I have so far, How would I allocate memory for a new node and initalize the value, then return a pointer to it? Not sure if I have the right approach.

Correction:

```
struct nodeStruct* List_createNode(int item) {
    struct nodeStruct node* = (struct nodeStruct *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodeStruct));
    if (node == NULL) {return NULL;}
    node->value = item;
    return node;
}
```

Would this return a pointer to a new node?

Comment: You need to allocate the memory *before* you can write to it.  Get rid of the `tempNode`, move the `malloc` up to the top and check its return value for `NULL`.  Also look at your compiler's output.  The above code should produce a whole pile of error messages.

Comment: You've got a bug in your return statement, return tempnnode, also in such a simple example, don't set tempnnode.value if tempnnode is NULL

Comment: Don't implement all of @5gon12eder suggestions, you need tempnode

Comment: @rhubarbdog: why? The variable `node` or the variable `tempNode` is needed, but not both. The code could be `struct nodeStruct *List_createNode(int item) { nodeStruct *node = malloc(sizeof(*node)); if (node != 0) node->value = item; return node; }`. You can spell `node` as `tempNode` consistently if you prefer, but the 'temp' appellation isn't accurate — the node survives longer than the function, so maybe  `permNode` would be a better name (though `new_node` would be simple and accurate, or `newNode` in camelCase), but in a simple function like this, the unqualified name `node` is sufficient.

Comment: The edited version of the code is OK.  There are those who will excoriate the use of the [cast on `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/), but it's necessary if the code will be compiled by a C++ compiler rather than a C compiler.  In my sample code, I wrote `nodeStruct *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));` which omits the cast (though I have plenty of my own code with casts because it is bilingual in C and the C subset of C++), and uses `sizeof(*node))` which adapts automatically to changes of type (unlike your proposed version which mentions the type 3 times on a single line).

Comment: I should also have observed that you need to set `node->next = NULL;` in the function, so that things don't go haywire if you try to follow the list starting at `node`.  [Rawnish](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3911658/rawnish) did make an assignment to `node->next` in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28134084/15168), pointing out the error (oversight) in my comment/answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I get this error, `expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘struct’
 struct nodeStruct* List_createNode(int item) {`
 ^

Comment: There's a semicolon missing at the end of the structure definition in the code fragment in the question.  Also, inside the function, the variable should be declared `struct nodeStruct *node` (you can only omit the `struct` if you're using C++, or if you create `typedef struct nodeStruct nodeStruct;`).  That's correct in your code; it is incorrect in my comment — just as well it is a comment!

Answer (score -1):

```
struct nodeStruct* List_createNode(int item) {
    struct nodeStruct node* = (struct nodeStruct *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodeStruct));
    if (node == NULL) {return NULL;}
    node->value = item;
    node->next=*head;  head is the current state pointer
    head=node;
    return head;
}
```

this should work

Comment: It wasn't my down-vote, but…you managed to introduce `head` which was not mentioned in the question.  You did set `node->next` to a value, which is a very good idea; it is just the choice of value that is debatable.  And, if you need to use `node->next = *head;` then you need to write `*head = node;` and return `*head` (or `node`).